# How to count how many specific weekdays appear between two variable dates? And then show date by date how many events happened?

Tags: google-bigquery

I apologize if the question title is not clear, but I will try to clarify my issue in this description:

I have a table containing flights schedules with the specific schema and example:

| id | departure_country | arrival_country | frequency | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Germany | Poland | ..3.5.. | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-30 |
| 35 | France | Portugal | .2.4..7 | 2023-02-11 | 2023-04-15 |

- frequency means which days of the week the flight occurs, 1 being Mondays, 2 being Tuesdays and so on.

My final output should be a table with how many flights occur per day from specific countries.
My idea so far is to create a table keeping the same structure, but splitting the frequency into each number and counting how many of each weekday occurs between the two dates (start and end date) to reach the total flights happening for this period.

I feel like maybe I'm tackling this issue in the wrong way. Apart from the issues with the code I tried, I do not have any idea at this point on how to later count the total amount of flights per date since the code above would display it per ID. any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

This is the code I have so far to count how many flights per each ID (with comments explaining the issues found), but the code is not running due to the issues mentioned:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)))  -- bigquery does not recognize start_date and end_date

SELECT
  id,
  departure_country,
  arrival_country,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(frequency, r"([0-9])") AS frequencyNEW,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u',(select * from dates)) = frequencyNEW THEN 1 END)
FROM flights_table 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(frequencyNEW)   -- trying to flatten the data but bigquery does not recognize the frequencyNEW field
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6  -- groupby doesn't work because of the array created with the REGEXP
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNNEST(frequencyNEW)` is not possible, because the variable `frequencyNEW` is not defined yet. Please use a CTE or a sub-select or `UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(frequency, r"([0-9])"))`.

A fast solution is to use an inner `((Select  ... ))`. Here all dates are unnested and a `where` condition is used to filter the one on the right day of the week. Since BigQuery uses the Sunday as 1 and you want it to be 7, a `+6` and modulo 7 is applied. With `where frequency like '%7%'` for a Sunday in the date list, the `frequency` is checked for a `7`.

Depending on your desired output, please remove the `#`.

```sql
with tbl as (select "Germany" departure_country,"..3.5.." frequency,  date("2022-12-20") start_date,date("2022-12-30")end_date
union all select "France",".2.4..7",date("2023-02-11"),date("2023-04-15"))

select 
# *,
departure_country,sum(
((Select count(x) from unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date,end_date)) as x 
where frequency like '%'|| mod(extract(DAYOFWEEK from x)+6,7)||'%'   )) #as days
) #
 from tbl 
 group by 1 # please comment this line out
```

This script is quite slow if there more than 10000 rows in the table.